# API to find polygon for cities and administrative boundaries in India

Tags: polygon, geocoding, google-maps-api, data, india

I am new to GIS and learning basics by going through various forums. I am looking for a way to get polygon coordinates for any place (city, 2nd/3rd order administrative division) in India. I started with Google Maps but it only returns 2 lat/lng coordinates - NE and SW. I am looking for more points so that I can represent the place in its actual shape on the map.

I came across some sites like Wikimapia, Yahoo Geoplanet, Geonames etc which may serve the purpose but wanted to confirm which one would I should go with. I can write a script to call APIs provided or download one large XML/JSON file which has this info and then store it in my DB.

Comment: So what you're after is data? You can browse/search the internet for free data or contact your national mapping agency (if you have one). Data can be expensive, especially if it's up to date, so be sure you know what you want before you buy it. What sort of 'place' are you referring to? a state, province, town, city...

Comment: As I said, I found a couple of options but want opinions on which one I can go with. I don't need huge amounts of data as of now and not considering paid options. I am interested in cities, towns and their administrative divisions.

Comment: If you have a program like QGIS you can look at some data and make an informed decision, download a small part of any free data and see if it meets your requirements. Only you will know if the data is what you want.